# Computer asking me for login keyring I didn't set?

Tags: password

I recently acquired an Ubuntu Matrix netbook. When I leave it a while on, it locks 
itself up and asks me then for a password. Recently it asks me for another password that says:

> Enter password to unlock your login keyring.

I did not set this password. I also can't use the guest session. Maybe it's something simple but I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please write small capitals.

(you did switch off your machine and reboot back into desktop ? )

In "system tools" there is entry "system settings" - there again you can adjust
behaviour of your desktop-environment.

In "brightness and lock" you can change the time from 10 minutes up to one hour. I would set it on 30 minutes.

Then you have enough time to open konsole resp. terminal for to set a password. - better you have at least one password, than no password.

In Terminal is command:

```
passwd
```

then you enter your password twice.

now it is better to have a second password as admin of your netbook.

```
sudo su
```

(you type your new password from just before)

```
passwd
```

then you enter again your second password twice (different password).

dunno !
now your system is double-safe !

two times command

```
exit
```

and you are normal User again for your machine.

Comment: @seth thanks! i still have some questions i'm sorry. where do i begin to change my password ( the password i don't  know) i tried to follow your instructions but can you tell in a much simpler way. sorry not en expert